# can I create movie manually?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to create a movie using objective-c, is it possible? or have to use the camera related things?

[Edit]In fact, I want to know is there any API to create a movie, I want to show some pictures in the movie, so I cannot use camera related things.

Comment: Define "create manually". In theory, you can "create" any file structure you want as long as you know the correct file format.

Comment: I'll bet he wants to use an API. Personally, I'd be interested in knowing how to create an AVAsset or MPMoviePlayer compatible movie frame by frame in cocoa-touch with bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AVAssetWriter and AVAssetWriterInput in the [AVFoundation documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html).